# Instagram Slideshow Content Not Returning Via API

Tags: instagram-api

Instagram recently introduced a new feature allowing users to post multiple photos via a slideshow.

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/0/post-multiple-photos-instagram/

However, we are not seeing that content get returned when we GET /users/self/media/recent

Does anyone know how to get slideshow content from a user via the API?

Comment: It's returning the first image on my end.